# has_one association isn't working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following ActiveRecord models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :faculty
end

class Faculty < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :head, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
end
```

When I try to pull a user using this association with `faculty.head` I get the record without errors, but when I type `user.faculty` I get an error:

```
  Faculty Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "faculties".* FROM "faculties" WHERE "faculties"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...".* FROM "faculties"  WHERE "faculties"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT ...
```

My `faculties` db schema looks like this:

```
create_table "faculties", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
    t.string   "user_id"
 end
```

Is this some PG bug??

Comment: What is the schema of your faculties table?

Comment: Strange!! Please try belongs_to :head, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'user_id'

Comment: @BachanSmruty How is it supposed to fix the problem? The problem is with `has_one :faculty` association.

Comment: the same problem with ***'user_id'***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs because you have your `user_id` column as a string, not integer.

Answer (score 2):

As your `user_id` is a `foreign_key` it should be `integer`

```
t.string   "user_id"
```

should be

```
t.integer   "user_id"
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message says:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
```

It means that you are trying to compare a varchar value (the `user_id` field of the `faculties` table) and an integer value (the `id` field of the `users` table), this is not allowed.

You have to define the foreign key `user_id` as `integer`:

```
create_table "faculties", :force => true do |t|
    # ...
    t.integer "user_id"
 end
```